# How to use "this" in a function passed as a "prop" to a subcomponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS.

I have a component that renders a subcomponent, I'm passing a function as a `prop`. However, I can't use `this` in the function handler.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    onChildStatusChanged: function () {
        // this.state is undefined, of course, because this function hasn't been called from this object context.
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <SubComponent onStatusChanged={this.onChildStatusChanged} />
        </div>
    }
```

How can I use `this` in the `onChildStatusChanged`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind the current `this` context to the `this.onChildStatusChanged` function using `bind`.

`this.onChildStatusChanged.bind(this)`

The `bind` function will return a function equal to `onChildStatusChanged` but with the `this` context set to the one you specify.

`bind` is an ES5 feature so if you're targeting systems < ES5 you'll need to polyfil this function.

**Update**

You add the bind in your current event assignment:

`<SubComponent onStatusChanged={this.onChildStatusChanged.bind(this)} />`

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly would I call `this.onChildStatusChanged.bind(this)`?

Comment: You could also use arrow functions which have an implicit `.bind(this)`, e.g. `<SubComponent onStatusChanged={e => this.onChildStatusChanged(e) } />`.  These are also often succinct enough to do simple operations inline, e.g. `<Sub onChange={e => this.setState({foo: e.target.value})} />`